# Npm - Local added package not working under windows when running node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, package.json

in my package.json, I have a local added package like so:

```
"my-package": "./extern/my-package"
```

This is working under my mac, but not under my windows pc. When I run this node.js command in the `Project` folder:

```
node my-script.mjs
```

under windows, I got:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'C:\Development\Project\node_modules\my-package\' imported from C:\Development\Project\my-script.mjs
 at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at legacyMainResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:335:9)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:877:14)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:929:18)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1044:11)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:422:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:222:40)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

I also tried an absolut path like so:

```
"my-package": "C:\\Development\\Project\\extern\\my-package",
```

Without success

The `package.json` from my-package should be fine, cause on mac, he can import it.

I use `yarn` as the package manager. When I run

```
yarn add ./extern/my-package
```

The package is also added to the package.json like shown above. What I want to say, the setup of my local package should be fine :) Also tried `npm`, by the way.

Is there something different on windows, what I don't see?

Comment: Not sure, if I'm misunderstanding something, but you realized the issue is with `p5js-node` and not you own package (assuming both are different).

Comment: Fixed it in my question. I just wrote my-package instead of p5js-node, because I setup a example project for myself. The typing is correct in the code.